# Graph of a single point continuous function.

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity, graphing-functions

We often come across functions like f(x)= x, x belongs to rational and -x, when x belongs to irrational, which are continuous at just one (or more isolated) point, in this example at x=0. I googled to look at the graph of such a function, with no luck. Even desmos wouldn't let me type such a function. So, does anyone know how to find graph of such a function, can anybody share it here?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB8Fz.png

Comment: You can try a google-image search, such as [this image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=graph+rational+irrational+x&tbm=isch). Also of possible interest is the 1913 Masters thesis [**A Collection of Graphs to Accompany Certain Topics in the Study of Function Theory of a Real Variable**](https://mospace.umsystem.edu/xmlui/handle/10355/16194) by Ruth Eversole Perrault [*before 1925*: Ruth Eversole] (1891−1960).

Comment: You cannot graph it in a meaningful way. A graph is a visual representation and your eye will try to create a continuous line from it it can see.

Answer (score 1):

One can imagine what the graph would look like: since the rationals and irrationals are both dense, the graph would appear to be an X shape: the union of both the lines $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=-x$. Of course, if one could "zoom in infinitely", one would see that the lines are not really lines, but points that are infinitesimally close.